# nodejs - csv-write-stream gives me 'pipe is not a function' inside a callback to stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Whenever I run this code I get an error that says `csv.pipe is not a function`.

I think maybe is related to being inside a callback on stdout?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var speedtest = spawn('speedtest-cli',['--json']);
var csv = require('csv-write-stream')

speedtest.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    var down = (dataObj.download/1000000).toFixed(2);
    var up = (dataObj.upload/1000000).toFixed(2);

    csv.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('speed.csv',{flags: 'a'}));
    csv.write([dataObj.timestamp,down,up]);
    csv.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var speedtest = spawn('speedtest-cli',['--json']);
var csvWriteStream = require('csv-write-stream');
var csv = csvWriteStream();//I added this string

speedtest.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    var down = (dataObj.download/1000000).toFixed(2);
    var up = (dataObj.upload/1000000).toFixed(2);

    csv.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('speed.csv',{flags: 'a'}));
    csv.write([dataObj.timestamp,down,up]);
    csv.end();
});
```